# PHP LOGIN val_csrf()

Tags: php, admin, csrf

hello there I have a problem with the security csrf, so here is the code:

for file helps.php

```
session start(): 
function csrf_token()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION["token"])){
        unset($_SESSION["token"]);
    }
    $csrf_token = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(),true));
    $_SESSION["csrf_token"]=$csrf_token;
    echo $csrf_toker;
}
function val_csrf()
{
    if($_REQUEST["_token"]==$_SESSION["csrf_token"]){
       return true;
    }else{
       return false;
    }
}
```

for file AuthController.php the error is this: 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function val_csrf() in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectos\sistemaventas\app\controller\AuthController.php on line 19

```
<?php
use \vista\Vista;
use App\model\User;
use libreria\ORM\LiORM;
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Usuario
 * Date: 30/03/2017
 * Time: 3:37 AM
 */

class AuthController
{
    public function index(){
        return Vista::crear("auth.login");
    }

public function ingresar(){
    if(val_csrf()){       <<<<<<--- the error es here!!
        $email = input("email");
        $password = encriptar(input("password"));
        $objOrm = new LiORM();
        $data = $objOrm->Ejecutar("login",array($email,$password));

        if(count($data) > 0){
            $_SESSION['id'] = $data[0]["id"];
            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $data[0]["usuario"];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $data[0]["email"];
            $_SESSION['privilegio'] = $data[0]["privilegio"];

            redirecciona()->to("admin");
        }else{
            redirecciona()->to("/admin")->withMessage(array( //url debe ser /login, lo cambie para continuar.
                "estado"=>"false",
                "mensaje"=>"Usuario/Password incorrectos"
            ));
        }

    }else{
        echo "esta mal";
    }
}
```

and this is my login.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Sistema de ventas | Login</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="<?php asset("bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css") ?>" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
<link href="<?php asset("bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css")?>" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="<?php asset("dist/css/sb-admin-2.css")?>" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="<?php asset("bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css") ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title text-center">Ingresar al sistema</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form role="form" action="<?php url("login/ingresar") ?>" method="post">
                        <input value="<?php csrf_token() ?>" name="_token" type="hidden">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="contoso@gmail.com" name="email" type="email" required autocomplete="off" autofocus>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" required>
                            </div>
                           <!-- <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Recordarme
                                </label>
                            </div>-->
                            <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Login</button>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                    <br>
                    <?php if(Session::has("estado") && Session::has("mensaje")){ ?>

                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <strong>Error! </strong> <?php echo Session::get("mensaje");  ?>
                    </div>

                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="<?php asset("bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js")?>"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="<?php asset("bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js")?>"></script>

<!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="<?php asset("bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js")?>"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="<?php asset("dist/js/sb-admin-2.js")?>"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have a missing quote in `unset($_SESSION["token]);` so everything after that is part of the string.

Comment: @Barmar yes man! I fixed it now, but I still have the problem:
Notice: Undefined index: csrf_token . On my  function val_csrf()

Comment: If you call `ingresar()` before the first time you call `csrf_token()` you'll get that error because the session variable isn't set yet.

Comment: @Barmar yes! you were rigth! I solve the problem adding a new user with the correct encryption. Thanks man!